# How to integrate $\int_0^T K_{\lambda}(t,s) \sigma(s)ds$ using scipy.integrate

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I need to integrate the expression

[image: Integral]

using scipy's integrate module.

I have tried

```
def K(t,s):
    return np.exp(lbda*(T-s))*np.exp(lbda*t)/(1-np.exp(lbda*T))

def sigma(s):
    return np.sin(2*np.pi*s)

def integral(t):
    result = integrate.quad(K*sigma, 0, T)
    return  result
```

But obviously it's wrong since `K` has two variables, one of which would be undefined. How do I proceed?

For reference the function integral would be called with different values for `t`.

Comment: Doesn't `quad` take a `args` tuple?  Or let `t` be a global.  In either case, you have to call `quad` once for each value of `t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `quad` must be a callable whose first parameter is the integration variable.  You'll have to create a new function (or use a lambda expression) for the integrand that calls your existing functions.  It is also probably a good idea to make *all* the parameters that you'll use into function arguments, to avoid the need for global variables.  You can pass these in via the `args` parameter of `quad`.

For example,

```
def K(t, s, lbda, T):
    return np.exp(lbda*(T-s))*np.exp(lbda*t)/(1-np.exp(lbda*T))

def sigma(s):
    return np.sin(2*np.pi*s)

def integrand(s, t, lbda, T):
    return K(t, s, lbda, T) * sigma(s)

def integral(t, lbda, T):
    result = integrate.quad(integrand, 0, T, args=(t, lbda, T))[0]
    return result
```

Then the code that uses these function might look something like this:

```
# Define the parameters
lbda = 1.25
T = 8.0

# Define the t value.
t = 0.5

# Evaluate the integral at t.
y = integral(t, lbda, T)
```